# Implode EOF with new line character

Tags: php

I have an EOF string and i want to implode it with new line character, I tried the following but the $imploded variable remains null. Any help please ?

```
        $s = <<<EOF
NAME=Test Test
PHONE_PASSWORD= 000
CITY= test
STATE=
EOF;

 $imploded = implode("\n",$s);
```

Comment: `implode()` expects an array not a string.  What are you actually trying to do?

Comment: as above states you using the wrong function, I believe you're looking for [`explode`](http://www.php.net/explode)

Comment: @Dale Either that or OP can't get the new lines to display in the resulting HTML, in which case something like `nl2br` is needed.

Comment: `Warning: implode(): Invalid arguments passed` is what you should have posted for the error you got, or should be getting.

Comment: Can you please explain what your goal is as it's currently hard to get what you want

Comment: you need to explode and `foreach`, easy fix. Shall I post that for you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As others (and myself) have stated in comments, you need to use `explode()` and not `implode()` as that would have thrown an error about it such as:

> Warning: implode(): Invalid arguments passed...

Therefore and with a `foreach`:

```
$imploded = explode("\n",$s);

foreach($imploded as $var){

    echo $var;

}
```

Resulting in:

`NAME=Test TestPHONE_PASSWORD= 000CITY= testSTATE=`

---

Error reporting:

- http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php